# Is there a way to use elasticsearch collapse feature using searchkick gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

The feature I am interested in is documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/collapse-search-results.html). I tried adding it as a parameter to the search method but it seems like it is unsupported. Is there any easy way to access this feature when using the searchkick gem?

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than I expected. You can add the following to the query: `body_options: {collapse: {field: :field_to_collapse_by}}`